# Как можно вывести картинку по нажатию кнопки?

Tags: java, android

Решил написать программу, выводящую определенную картинку по нажатию определенной кнопки, но приложение вылетает при нажатии этой кнопки. Как это можно исправить?

```
package com.example.fando.trenazher;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;



public class game1 extends AppCompatActivity {
Button buttonQ;
Button buttonW;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game1);
    buttonQ = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    buttonW = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    buttonQ.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View View) {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.petuh);
        }
    });
    buttonW.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View View) {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.lion);

        }
    });
        }}
```

в логах ошибка описывается так

```
11-07 15:23:35.819 25682-25682/com.example.fando.trenazher       
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.fando.trenazher, PID: 25682
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.fando.trenazher.game1$2.onClick(game1.java:30)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run  (ZygoteInit.java:779)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

З.Ы. Не судите строго, я только учусь (:

Comment: Возможно, стоит посмотреть в лог по поводу этой ошибки и, желательно, выложить необходимую часть сюда?

Comment: Только что запустил у себя и не вылетает. Действительно  лучше запустить пошагово и выявить ошибку. В процесе тестирования  желательно смотреть в консоль или в Android Monitor, там среда подскажет даже на какой строчке крашнулось и почему

Comment: Проверьте наличие ресурсов, соответствующих идентификаторам, которые присутствуют у Вас в коде.

Comment: в layout  (R.layout.activity_game1) есть ImageView с id  image ??? скорей всего его нет, дело в этом

Comment: да, было бы здорово еще макет увидеть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй Так

```
// принять переменную ImageView

    private ImageView mImageView;

// Связать ImageView с идентификатором вашего XML в

    mImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.mImageView);

// Набор ресурсов для ImageView

mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_image_name);
```

Comment: Во-первых, искать `view` нужно в метода `onCreate`. Делать это, например, в слк